# Chrome Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mutation-observers

I'm trying to use the Mutation Observer in Chrome to monitor when a new image is added,here is my code so far:

```
var observer = new window.MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var m = mutation;
        //console.log(m);
        for (var j = 0; j < m.addedNodes.length; j++)
        {
            var nodes=m.addedNodes[j];
            if (!nodes || !nodes.querySelectorAll)
            {
                // Not all nodes support querySelectorAll, e.g. text nodes.
                continue;
            }

            var imgs= nodes.querySelectorAll("img");
            for (var k = 0; k < imgs.length; k++)
            {
                if(imgs[k].src != undefined)
                {
                    var img = imgs[k];
                    console.log(img);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

var config = { childList: true };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(window.document, config);
```

A weird thing is happening: the callback seems to be called but doesn't find any images.When I open console(*Ctrl+Shift+J*) the code starts working fine,all the images added by that point are printed.The same thing happens when I re-size the console opened.

Do I have to set additional parameters to the config value?
Why is opening the console suddenly make the code work?

Comment: any details on how that new image is added? Was it added through creating an `<img>` element in the dom? Or there was already an `<img>` and you just changed the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The document's child list almost never changes. It's usually just a single `<html>` child. You might have wanted `subtree: true` in your `config`, so that the observer would run if an image is added deep in the document.

This doesn't explain why the code was working when the console was open though.